# I got this error: {"code":5,"message":"Unsupported protocol version"}

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is the server side:

```
 var socketIO = require("socket.io")(http);
 var socketID = "";
 var users = [];

 var mainURL = "http://localhost:3000";

 socketIO.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("User connected", socket.id);
    socketID = socket.id;
 });
```

Everything works perfectly but when I try to start the app everything
stops I can see this in the console, qualqu someone to guide me
please?